# Kudan for Unity v1.2.2: Creating Custom Markers

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan

I'm trying to get started with Kudan in Unity using Kudan package v.1.2.2 on Mac OS. I have spent quite long time trying just to test detecting my own marker but I always fail. Here are the steps I did:

1. Downloaded both Unity package and Kudan ARTool Kit.
2. Created new Unity Project and deleted default components.
3. Imported Kudan Package.
4. Draged and dropped "Kudan Camera" and added my Editor API Key.
5. In Kudan ARTool kit, I created a new project and imported a simple marker (.png file):
   [simple marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV7jF.png)
6. Recorded the marker dimensions, which were 300x300.
7. I then exported the marker to a .KARMarker file.
8. In Unity, I clicked on "Add KARMarker Asset" and selected my .KARMarker.
9. Then, I dragged the created .asset file to MarkerTracking component.
10. Finally, I run the player mode. It runs without problem, but never detects my marker.

Appreciate if anyone can help me on what I missed, or what I wrong steps I did.

** Please note that the application runs perfectly without my custom marker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your steps sound correct, the issue that I think is causing you this issue is the marker that you have chosen. It has sharp contrasts which is great but rather lacks interesting feature points to make it a good reliable marker.

I would recommend having a look at Kudan's article about [what makes a good marker](https://wiki.kudan.eu/What_Makes_a_Good_Marker%3F). After you have chosen something that fits the criteria better, you should find that your sample should work.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right.
I changed the marker and used some of Kudan's good markers and it has been detected. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have markerless tracking by default and don't marker tracking.
And you put good expected id in marker transform driver script of your gameObject that you want to watch?

Comment: I am using the MarkerTracking "TrackingMethodMarker" script. The problem was with type of marker, although I expected to work. Thanks anyways.